# Why won't my BufferedReader work at reading a text file?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Why won't my BufferedReader work? I'm trying to read a text file using a BufferedReader, but each time I run the program it says there's an error in my line:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("playerinfo.txt"));
```

I'm still learning, and I can't figure out what's wrong with my BufferedReader. I'm trying to make it read a text file of the players stats and then output the file. I made a text file to read from, but the error still appears each time I try to run my program. I've tried to look up similar questions to mine, but there seems to be a few ways to do a BufferedReader, and I think mine looks like it should be working.I can't find any other parts in my code that seem wrong, but I'm still rather new. Any help on this problem is much appreciated.

Here's how I'm trying to implement it:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Player { //Base class
    String name;
    float weight;
    int age;

    Player() {
    }

    ;

    Player(String name, float weight, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

class Defensive extends Player {
    int tackles, interceptions;
    float sacks;

    Defensive() {
        super();
    }

    Defensive(String name, float weight, int age, int tackles, int interceptions, float sacks) {
        super(name, weight, age);
        this.tackles = tackles;
        this.interceptions = interceptions;
        this.sacks = sacks;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "name : " + name + ", weight : " + weight + ", age : " + age + ", tackles : " + tackles + ", sacks : " + sacks + ", interceptions : " + interceptions + "\n";
    }
}

class Football { //main class
    public Defensive readDefensive(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
        String name = br.readLine();
        float weight = Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
        int age = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int tackles = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        float sacks = Float.parseFloat(br.readLine());
        int interceptions = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        return (new Defensive(name, weight, age, tackles, interceptions, sacks));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Football football = new Football();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("playerinfo.txt"));
        String line = br.readLine();
        Defensive defensive = new Defensive();
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        while (line != null) {
            if (line.equals("defensive")) {
                defensive = football.readDefensive(br);
                al.add(defensive);
            }
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        System.out.println(al);
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hampster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: so what is the error ?

Comment: My error reads:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: playerinfo.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Try putting the full path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your class Football containing main method should be declared as `public class`.

Also you should consider using generics lists as your implementation produces warnings right now.
Use `List<Defensive> defensives = new ArrayList<>();`